# Cant get data using LIKE with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a simple search using php. I'm trying to display data from 2 tables using INNER JOIN and LIKE. Using the keyword I need to check if the keyword exist on one of the tables. my problem is its not showing any data.

it also shows a warning `Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object`

Thanks.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];

        if($keyword != ""){

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM history_search INNER JOIN history_subs ON history_search.keyword = history_subs.keyword WHERE keyword LIKE '%$keyword%'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo $row['keyword'];
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        }
```

Comment: debug the result , maybe the problem is there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get property 'num\_rows' of non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50002520/trying-to-get-property-num-rows-of-non-object)

Comment: whats the type of the column varchar or text ?

Comment: sorry guys, I update the question. Im really sorry.

Comment: @Naveen its `varchar`

Comment: Ill make a new thread since what I added is a new problem.

Comment: Instead of Exact match with the keywords column in two tables, you can query a single table with like $keyword

Comment: Be aware of [Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). This code is open for SQL injection.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Ill work on that later. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column name `keyword` is ambiguous as it appears in both tables

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM history_search 
INNER JOIN history_subs 
    ON history_search.keyword = history_subs.keyword 
WHERE history_search.keyword LIKE '%$keyword%' -- Added a table reference here
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly question. But if you are using a WHERE clause with a LIKE then the Keyword field MAY only contain that keyword in the whole field. However on your join you are join as an exact match for the same field.

What I am getting at is if you had 2 keyword fields that contained comments for example, then why are they joining on an exact match? If you remove the where clause are you then returning any results?